# Change class of Bootstrap 'label' in a table <td>

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a mysql data of around 2000 rows, column "Status" has value either "Paid" or "Unpaid" displaying in  tag.
I want to change the class of  depending on its value with jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var val = $('#check').text();
        if (val === "Paid") {
          $('.label').addClass(' label-success');
        }
        if (val === "Unpaid") {
          $('.label').addClass(' label-danger');
        }
```

I have tried this so far (eg in fiddle): **[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/sohal/edvw76o1/2/)**

Comment: `id` should be unique

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/edvw76o1/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop through all of the labels..

```
  $('.label').each(function(i,ele){

    var val = $(ele).text();
    if (val === "Paid") {
      $(ele).addClass('label-success');
    }
    if (val === "Unpaid") {
      $(ele).addClass('label-danger');
    }

  });
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/tf8zFOsQBr

Also, `id` should be a unique identifier so there shouldn't be more that 1 element named "status".

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery's filter: http://api.jquery.com/filter/

```
var paid = $('.label').filter(function(){
  return $(this).text() == "Paid"
});
var unpaid = $('.label').filter(function(){
  return $(this).text() == "Unpaid"
});

console.log(paid);
console.log(unpaid);

paid.addClass('label-success');
unpaid.addClass('label-danger');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sohal/edvw76o1/2/